Why do I make an api request when building Next.js SSG?
I am currently in a situation where I composed Next.js v14, PageRouter, and react-query v5 as a project.
The Home page component of src/pages/index.tsx did not use getStaticProps, but the part that you wrote console.log in the axios logic at the time of build is output to the terminal.
Why is this happening??
First of all, the Home page component.
// src/pages/index.tsx

import Innter from "@/components/Innter";

export default function Home() {
  return <Innter />;
}

The next Inner component is a Test component wrapped in Suspense.
// src/components/Innter.tsx

import Image from "next/image";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Test from "@/components/Test";

function Innter() {
  return (
    <main
      className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24`}
    >
      <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
        <p className="fixed left-0 top-0 flex w-full justify-center border-b border-gray-300 bg-gradient-to-b from-zinc-200 pb-6 pt-8 backdrop-blur-2xl dark:border-neutral-800 dark:bg-zinc-800/30 dark:from-inherit lg:static lg:w-auto  lg:rounded-xl lg:border lg:bg-gray-200 lg:p-4 lg:dark:bg-zinc-800/30">
          Get started by editing&nbsp;
          <code className="font-mono font-bold">src/pages/index.tsx</code>
        </p>
        <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 flex h-48 w-full items-end justify-center bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-white dark:from-black dark:via-black lg:static lg:h-auto lg:w-auto lg:bg-none">
          <a
            className="pointer-events-none flex place-items-center gap-2 p-8 lg:pointer-events-auto lg:p-0"
            href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template-tw&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            By{" "}
            <Image
              src="/vercel.svg"
              alt="Vercel Logo"
              className="dark:invert"
              width={100}
              height={24}
              priority
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <Test /> */}
      <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
        <Test />
      </Suspense>
      <div className="relative flex place-items-center before:absolute before:h-[300px] before:w-full sm:before:w-[480px] before:-translate-x-1/2 before:rounded-full before:bg-gradient-radial before:from-white before:to-transparent before:blur-2xl before:content-[''] after:absolute after:-z-20 after:h-[180px] after:w-full sm:after:w-[240px] after:translate-x-1/3 after:bg-gradient-conic after:from-sky-200 after:via-blue-200 after:blur-2xl after:content-[''] before:dark:bg-gradient-to-br before:dark:from-transparent before:dark:to-blue-700/10 after:dark:from-sky-900 after:dark:via-[#0141ff]/40 before:lg:h-[360px]">
        <Image
          className="relative dark:drop-shadow-[0_0_0.3rem_#ffffff70] dark:invert"
          src="/next.svg"
          alt="Next.js Logo"
          width={180}
          height={37}
          priority
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Innter;

Next, the Test component displays the data of the api on the screen using useSuspenseQuery.
// src/components/Test.tsx

import { getHealthCheck } from "@/api/common";
import { useSuspenseQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function Test() {
  const { data } = useSuspenseQuery({
    queryKey: ["test"],
    queryFn: getHealthCheck,
  });
  const testData = data as any;


  return <div>{testData?.message}</div>;
}

export default Test;

Finally, the axios file calling api. Here, we are returning the response in 5 seconds (for the suspense fallbak test)
// src/api/common.ts

import { api } from ".";

export const getHealthCheck = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("hey api space!!!");
    const response = await api.get("/core/health_check");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(response.data), 5000);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Health check failed:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

The console.log ("hey api space!!!") in these axios codes is output at the time of terminal build, why??
build terminer image
I checked the official documents of Next.js and react-query, but I couldn't find anything about doing an api request without using getStaticProps during SSG build.

suspense runs on the server, but the pages router doesn't support streaming afaik. So the request runs on the server, but the result never makes it to the client. I don't think that you can use suspense queries in the pages router on the server.
